# JDBC using Azure Active Directory credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting wrong username or password when trying to make a JDBC connection to snowflake. I believe the culprit is that there is an Azure Active Directory layer between the connection. Is there a specific way I should be handling making this connection while using the azure credentials from my Java app through Azure Active Directory to Snowflake? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JDBC connection parameters, you need to set the `authenticator` parameter to `externalbrowser` or possibly depending on the setup `oauth` with a setting for the oauth `token` parameter.

You can read more about OAuth here, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html

The section specific to OAuth on JDBC on that page is here, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#label-jdbc-connection-parameters. Scroll down from that bookmark on the page to the `authenticator` parameter section.